# max-width element in Neat grid creates right margin

Tags: sass, haml, bourbon, neat

I am relatively new to Bourbon Neat and since the recent update I have been a little lost. I have a custom grid I have set up media queries for. The elements in the grid contain a 500x500 photo with a description underneath.  My problem is if I set a max-width to the div containing the image to 500px, the grid aligns left and a margin is produced on the right at widths that are greater than the elements+gutters.  If I remove the max-width, it centers perfectly but the containing div gets wider than the image which I don't want. How can I center my max-width elements at these widths? display: block; and margin: auto do nothing.

I am using HAML and SASS.

HAML:

```
.video-grid
  .video-section#film-tv
    %span.parallelogram
      %h2.parallelogram-title Film and TV
    .film-tv-videos
      %a{:href => "/hardearth/"}
        .video-slide-wrap
          .video-slide
            .video-slide-img-wrap
              %img.video-slide-img{:src => "/images/500x500/hard-earth.jpg"}
          %p.tiny-caption Teaser for Feature Film
          %h6.video-slide-title The Hard Earth
          %p.video-slide-description Documentary exploring America's relationship to Ukraine
      %a{:href => "/vaselinescreen/"}
        .video-slide-wrap
          .video-slide
            .video-slide-img-wrap
              %img.video-slide-img{:src => "/images/500x500/vaseline-screen.jpg"}
          %p.tiny-caption TV Show
          %h6.video-slide-title Vaseline Screen
          %p.video-slide-description Blur pop visions of what life could be like if we loved things we hate.
      %a{:href => "/videos/patrick"}
        .video-slide-wrap
          .video-slide
            .video-slide-img-wrap
              %img.video-slide-img{:src => "/images/500x500/patrick.jpg"}
          %p.tiny-caption Short Film
          %h6.video-slide-title Patrick Worth Dying For
          %p.video-slide-description Playing foreclosure as it lays.
      %a{:href => "/videos/californiapsych/"}
        .video-slide-wrap
          .video-slide
            .video-slide-img-wrap
              %img.video-slide-img{:src => "/images/500x500/california-psych.jpg"}
          %p.tiny-caption Short Film
          %h6.video-slide-title California Psych
          %p.video-slide-description Transcendental ending to an otherwise rotten country.
      %a{:href => "/videos/badcredit/"}
        .video-slide-wrap
          .video-slide
            .video-slide-img-wrap
              %img.video-slide-img{:src => "/images/500x500/bad-credit.jpg"}
          %p.tiny-caption Short Film
          %h6.video-slide-title Bad Credit Good Moms
          %p.video-slide-description Mom moves out of filmmaker's childhood home.
```

SASS:

```
$videos-grid: (
  columns: 4,
  gutter: 30px,
  media: 1660px,
);

$videos-grid-2:(
  columns: 3,
  gutter: 30px,
  media: 1440px,
);

$videos-grid-3: (
  columns: 3,
  gutter: 30px,
  media: 1140px,
);

$videos-grid-4: (
  columns: 2,
  gutter: 30px,
  media: 840px,
);

$videos-grid-5: (
  columns: 2,
  gutter: 30px,
  media: 570px,
);

$videos-grid-6: (
  columns: 1,
  gutter: 0px,
  media: 0px,
);


.video-section
  @include grid-container($videos-grid)
  width: 100%
  padding-bottom: 30px
  position: relative
  margin: 0

.video-slide-wrap
  @include grid-column(1, $videos-grid-6)
  @include grid-media($videos-grid-5)
    @include grid-column(1)
  @include grid-media($videos-grid-4)
    @include grid-column(1)
  @include grid-media($videos-grid-3)
    @include grid-column(1)
  @include grid-media($videos-grid-2)
    @include grid-column(1)
  @include grid-media($videos-grid)
    @include grid-column(1)
  max-width: 500px
  text-align: left
  display: block
  margin: auto

.video-slide
  height: auto
  position: relative
  margin: auto
  color: $black
  overflow: hidden

.video-slide-img-wrap
  display: block
  margin: auto
  height: auto
  width: 100%
  max-width: 500px

.video-slide-img
  display: block
  height: auto
  width: 100%

.video-slide-description
  display: block
  margin: auto
  padding: 5px
  font-size: 0.9em
  line-height: 1.2

.video-slide-title
  display: block
  margin: auto
  text-align: center
  margin-bottom: 5px

.tiny-caption
  font-size: .8em
  font-style: italic
```

With max-width: 500px on .video-slide-wrap:

[gap on right](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5tYVX.jpg)

With no max-width set on .video-slide-wrap:

[grid elements centered but ugly stuff around image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rjDXU.jpg)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*This is assuming your goal is to have a series of blue boxes w/ images that grow until each of them become 500px and then cease getting larger, but instead grow farther apart from one another.*

First up I think you should combine your `%a{:href => "…"}`'s and the `.video-slide-wrap` and then give `.video-slide` the blue `background-color` and `max-width`.

It's tough to backsolve your whole layout but this might look something like:

```
%a.video-slide-wrap{:href => "/vaselinescreen/"}
  .video-slide
    img
    text
```

and then for the sass

```
.video-slide-wrap
  @include grid-column(1, $videos-grid-6)
  @include grid-media($videos-grid-5)
    @include grid-column(1)
  @include grid-media($videos-grid-4)
    @include grid-column(1)
  @include grid-media($videos-grid-3)
    @include grid-column(1)
  @include grid-media($videos-grid-2)
    @include grid-column(1)
  @include grid-media($videos-grid)
    @include grid-column(1)

.video-slide
  max-width: 500px
  text-align: left
  display: block
  margin: 0 auto
  background: blue;
```

Something like that should probably™ work.